# Validating XHTML inside $.queue

Tags: javascript, xhtml, w3c, validation

I am using the following JavaScript:

```
.queue(function() {
            $('#num').html('10');
            element
                .html('First line<br /><span id="small">Small text<br />Small text again<br />small text again here</span>')
                .dequeue();
        })
```

When I run this through W3C's validator, it says "document type does not allow element br/span here".

Is there another way to do this to get it to validate?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use document.createElement(...) and add the created elements (appendChild)

Comment: HOw does that work? Sorry I'm a total JS beginner!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't get that error unless you are using XHTML (unless you get several other errors first), in which case you have to jump through the many hoops of "pretending your XHTML is HTML".

In this specific case, that is the guidelines for [Embedded Style Sheets and Scripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4).

In short, you should move your JS to an external file or wrap it in CDATA markers.

I recommend switching to HTML instead (unless you are actually using XML tools in your production chain, which most people are not).

Answer (score -1):

Use `pre` instead of multiple `span`'s and `br`'s:

```
'<pre>First line
Small text
Small text again
small text again here</pre>'
```

The following code works on stackoverflow.com using the JavaScript console and validates using the [W3C markup checker](http://validator.w3.org/check):

```
$("body").queue( function() { $(this).html("<pre>hi there</pre>") } ).dequeue();
```

Which would minimally generate:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head><title></title></head>
 <body>
 <pre>hi there</pre>
 </body>   
</html>
```

Comment: A pre element isn't allowed there either.

Comment: @Quentin In the W3C validator or jQuery?

Comment: Inside a `<script>` element. The use of jQuery is irrelevant. The validator just tells you that it isn't allowed.

Comment: @Quentin Where is the script element?

Comment: Around the JavaScript (unless the OP is trying to run a script file through a markup validator).

Comment: Re edit: *The following code works on stackoverflow.com* — as I explained in my answer, that error report should not show up unless XHTML is being used. Stackoverflow is not using XHTML.

Comment: Correct, running the code inside a script tag embedded in XHTML, then running it through a validator would cause this error. Good catch.